# SFSafariViewController details

Tags: ios, sfsafariviewcontroller

Here I am, using `SFSafariViewController` for the first time.
Before I would open `Safari` directly or use `WKWebView`, as everyone else I suppose.

Following some sample code I found on the web, here is a working function I wrote:

```
func openTheLink(_ urlStr: String) {
    let url = URL(string: urlStr)!
    let vc = SFSafariViewController(url: url, entersReaderIfAvailable: true)
    present(vc, animated: true)
}
```

Now I have two questions:

1. What is the purpose of the **entersReaderIfAvailable** parameter? I have tried to set it to true, then to false. I must admit, I didn't see any difference. Neither did I find any clear explanation.
2. When showing some web contents through the `SFSafariViewController`, is it still possible to show an advertising banner of my own, like I could do when using `WKWebView`?

Answer (score 0):

1. **entersReaderIfAvailable**
   On output, 
   true
   if Reader mode should be entered automatically when it is available for the web page; otherwise, 
   false.

   **Noted**: entersReaderIfAvailable applies only to the first page loaded.
2. Yes Sure.

Comment: I appreciate your kind comments, but that does not help me understand what this parameter is about (What is Reader mode?) and how I can see it in effect. Same for the second point, since the SFSafariViewController is taking all the space, how do I place my ad banner?